# tic tac toe andrdoid studio

Tags: java, android

I am making a tic tac toe game, i just created a array buttons. now i want to set a button with O and X then put in into a array but i don't know how to do that. I am new to android studio.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
 int turn;
 int[]myButton={R.id.button1,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.button4,
     R.id.button5,R.id.button6,R.id.button7,R.id.button8,R.id.button9,};
 int[]j= new int[10];
 Button button[]=new Button[myButton.length];
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       turn = 1;
         for (int i = 0; i < myButton.length; i++) {
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(myButton[i]);
        String Btn = String.valueOf(button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (button.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    if (turn == 1) {
                        turn = 2;
                        button.setText("X");
                    }
                        else if (turn == 2) {
                          turn = 1;
                          button.setText("O");
                        }
                }
                    endGame();
            }


         });
         }
     }
         public void endGame() {

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the thing is you have nine buttons but you dont know how to assign X or O for the players. I would suggest a solution like this. You have two players (A,B) and if A starts first, for the entire game he's going to go with label 'X' for his turns. For the other it's 'O'. You will have to mark your 9 buttons according to which player clicked it. Ex:- If 'A' clicked 'button5' then the button label should be turned to 'X'. likewise until all the buttons get clicked or someone wins the game continues. I only gave you the guidance. Come up with this implementation and let's resolve any new problems you have.

Comment: Thank you for you guidance. i finished assign the buttons. :D Now i am trying to do an endgame part. Normally i will call String a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i; Then compare each one to others. But i want to make it shorter and cleaner by using Array. Could you help me with the syntax ? Thank you.

Comment: @ZouBarney, yeah make an array size of nine and then do the assignment part (Player A clicks on button2 , it's properties become X). Also for each turn check for the winning patterns. We do not do the full code here. So you need to write it by yourself and you can accept my answer by checking the right mark below the voting arrows